# Clang warning for pointers in if, for, while, etc

Tags: objective-c, clang

Is it possible to get a warning for this code, where a pointer is used in an `if` statement?

```
NSObject *someObject = ...;
if (someObject) { // warning here
    ...
}
```

I would like to require this instead, for clarity and safety:

```
NSObject *someObject = ...;
if (someObject != nil) { // warning here
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do code review if you prefer the second style. The first is idiomatic in the C world as well, so getting any tool to warn about it is unlikely

Comment: This came as the first result of a google search: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-implicit-bool-conversion.html

Comment: You could use any MISRA-C checker to get a warning for the "sloppy style" version.

Comment: You could move to Swift to eliminate the possibility of the first type of code. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update** - thanks @rmaddy for pointing out the flaw in the original version.

One very, very hacky way would be to redefine `if` to something like this:

```
#define if(...) if ((__VA_ARGS__) == YES || (__VA_ARGS__) != NO)
```

thus an expression `if (someObject)` would be converted by the preprocessor to

```
if (someObject == YES || someObject != NO)
```

which would give a compile warning/error

> Comparison between pointer and integer ('NSObject *' and 'int')

Note that the error message is not very suggestive and might result in confusion, you should use the solution only if you really want to not allow expressions like `if (x)` to compile.

Both `== YES` and `!= NO` checks are needed, as @rmaddy correctly pointed out a `== YES` check will fail for expressions like `if (str.length)` when `str` is not exactly 1 character in length, and `== NO` alone is not enough as the compiler silently ignores comparison of pointers to `NO` (or to `0`, `NULL`).

And not lastly, this hack might result in function calls being made twice, if function calls are used within the `if`, so this might result in unexpected result if the function is not pure. So, beware :)

Comment: Using `== YES` is a bad idea. If anything, use `!= NO`.

Comment: @rmaddy that won't work, `NO` is equivalent to `nil`, using it will make no difference as the compiler happily converts between 0, `nil`, `NULL`, `NO`. Also some explanation of why using `YES` is not a good idea would've been good for the readers that stumble upon your comment.

Comment: `YES` is essentially `1`. So using `== YES` will only be true if the compared value is `1`. But `if` evaluates as "true" for any non-zero value, not just `1`.

Comment: @rmaddy hmm... you do have a valid point, valid expression like `if (str.count)` won't pass the redefined `if`, even if they should. I've updated the answer.